# Declaring stores, models and views in app.js?

Tags: model-view-controller, sencha-touch-2

I want to know if it is an obligation to declar all stores/Models/views that my application has in the app.js ? I'm saying that because I have tested the following situation : declaring just controllers in app.js and then trying to set needed stores/Models/Views in the corresponding controller.js, but doesn't work [undefined store...] !
in my case I'm structuring the application in modules like this :

```
app.js
Sales
-- salesController.js
-- salesStore.js
-- salesModel.js
-- salesView_1.js
Account
-- accountController.js
-- accountStore.js
-- accountModel.js
-- accountView_1.js
-- accountView_2.js

and so on...
```

Any information about this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to what the question's owner said, he has already known how to define an application in MVC structure. **The point is: why `Ext.require` in controllers alone does not work, right?**

There are some descriptions about explicit definition of `controllers,stores,models,views` in `app.js`:

- profiles - instantiates each Profile and determines if it should be active. If so, the Profile's own dependencies are also loaded
- controllers - instantiates each Controller after loading
- stores - instantiates each Store, giving it a default store ID if one is not specified

It means that all of those necessary stuffs are **initiated** before and right when your application is loaded. But `Ext.require` does not, because it's designed for **asynchronous** way. For example, say that in your controller (which you requires all other stuffs: models, views, stores), you jump in a view that use a store, which is defined by **class**, not any **initiated instance**, so it left undefined.

Shortly to say, the formal way to declare all required stuffs in `app.js` ensures you have an instance (of controller/store/model/view) when you need it. But `Ext.require` support your class code, not instance initialization.

Comment: from this, I think this way might work (I'm unsure because I've never tried it before): using `Ext.syncRequire`

Comment: Yes, I have also tested Ext.require. So what I'm understanding from you answer is that we should declar all stuffs in app.js to be able to use instances? Thanks!